# progressive download with authentication and playback in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avasset

**What i am trying to achieve:**

- Progressive download with authentication
- Should be able to play as the chunk of data comes (urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data))

---

**What i tried till now:**

- Tried with `AVAudioPlayer(data: tempData as Data)`, by appending data to the tempData as the data received in url session.
  But player plays for first set of data and stops.
- Integrated using AVAsset

> ```
> func initializePlayer() {
>         //audio session for handling interuptions - Done Appdelegate
>         /*
>          1. Create Asset (Asset represent a single media), AVAsset ->     AVAssetTrack
>          2. Resource properties like metadata, duration etc are loaded from asset, but if taken syncrn will block so use async
>          */
>
> }
> ```

```
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "big_buck_bunny", ofType: "mp4")
        let resourceUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!)
        let asset = AVAsset(url: resourceUrl)

        let playableKey = "playable"


        // Load the "playable" property

        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [playableKey]) { [unowned self] in

            var error: NSError? = nil

            let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: playableKey, error: &error)

            switch status {

            case .loaded:
                debugPrint("Sucessfuly loaded")
                self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                self.playerItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), options: [.old, .new], context: &audioPlayerInterfaceViewControllerKVOContext)
                self.playerItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.duration), options: [.new, .initial], context: &audioPlayerInterfaceViewControllerKVOContext)
                self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)
                let interval = CMTimeMake(1, 1)
                self.timeObserveToken = self.player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [unowned self] time in
                    let timeElapsed = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time))
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
                        self.durationSlider.setValue(Float(timeElapsed), animated: true)

                    })
                    self.startTimeLabel.text = self.createTimeString(time: timeElapsed)
                }

                break

                // Sucessfully loaded. Continue processing.

            case .failed:
                self.showErrorAlert(errorString: "Failed to load")
                debugPrint("failed")
                break

                // Handle error

            case .cancelled:
                self.showErrorAlert(errorString: "Failed to load")
                debugPrint("Cancelled")
                break

                // Terminate processing

            default:
                debugPrint("Error occured")
                self.showErrorAlert(errorString: "Failed to load")
                break

                // Handle all other cases

            }

        }
    }
```

Successfully played local file. But How could we append the part of data to AVAsset that entire data would be played?

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayer is not suitable for streaming audio from the network. You'll want to read up on Audio File Stream Services: https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/1669809-audio_file_stream_services

Comment: Thanks, finally we got streaming url. So using the AVPlayer with its URL option now

Comment: So... everything is working for you now? I'm confused by your comment.

Comment: Initially my clients requirement was to 
1. Download the file from an authenticated url, and when a small chunk of data is received it need to be played. (non streaming URL), But it didn't seem to work well.
So created a URL with streaming capabilities and another URL for downloading. With help of AVPlayer with URL the issue got resolved. Thanks

Comment: Ah, ok. So some changes were made on the backend that made things work out for you.

Comment: yeah. Thanks @Dave :)